# CSS property not applied

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mainbody, #mainbodyloginpage {
    left: 35%;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}
#mainbodyloginpage {
    top: 55%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mainbodyloginpage">
..
..
```

**.. [ top property not applied here ]**
    ..

```
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

any idea why the top property is not being applied, other property like left is applied.?

update::
as soon as i change

```
top: 55%;
```

to

```
top: 20px;
```

it works. but i dont want to hardcore it to a fixed value.
Anybody have any insight what going on here?

Update2::
This code work perfectly fine in IE but not in firefox/chrome. i.e chrome and firefox ignores the top property set as a percentage. IE does honour it.

Comment: I suggest either using Firebug or Google Chrome to inspect the CSS and then seeing the reason. Other solutions could be to apply the `!important` keyword to the `top` value.

Comment: In the style tab firebug shows                           #mainbodyloginpage {
    top: 55%;
}
mycss.css (line 52)
#mainbody, #mainbodyloginpage {
    left: 35%;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
} looks like atleast firebug sees it as property i don't know why it didn't applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifically set position: relative as position: static is the default. top/left/etc don't have any effect on statically position elements.

Comment: my problem is not of left property .. left property is already working for me but the top is not

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp says top should work in this situation even with relative positioning!

Comment: The same thing applies, the element has to be position: absolute for top, bottom, left, right.. Try margin-top or change the element to position: aboslute and make sure its parent container is position: relative.

Comment: i guess margin-top is different from top. i see in the http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp left should work. it says "For relatively positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right to its normal position."

Comment: Ahh, you haven't specifically set that to position: relative.. the default is position: static

Comment: #mainbody, #mainbodyloginpage {
    left: 35%;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}
so #mainbodyloginpage should have position relative?

Comment: @David: I wouldn't be using W3C Schools as a canonical resource. See http://w3fools.com/ why. I would recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Centre](http://developer.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `position` to `absolute`.

Don't know if you want it absolute in your scenario, but works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UL5pD/

```
#mainbody, #mainbodyloginpage {
    left: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
}
#mainbodyloginpage {
    top: 55%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. absolute works. but relative positioning don't. I don't know why? Also in IE relative also work. but firefox and chrome don't take the top property!